# Using Jupyter notebook with LaTex. Images not exported to pdf via LaTex

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

New to Juypter, trying to use it with Latex. Everything works fine except for the images. I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3o1KXA1Rjk&t=149s

Png Images are fine in markdown, i.e

But LaTex cannot determine size of png images. If I save the image as pdf I get the same issue. If I save the image as eps then LaTex complains that it cannot convert eps to pdf.

Has anyone had this issue? Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

PNG images *always* contain the size in pixels.

*Optionally*, they can include a chunk of data named `pHYs`. This contains the resolution of the image. If this chuck is present, you should be able to find the actual text `pHYs` in the file.

If this chunk is missing from the PNG file, the scale of the image can not be found.

If you are on a UNIX-like operating system you could use `grep` or `hexdump` to check for the text `pHYs` in the PNG file. The `identify` program from the ImageMagick suite also can display the resolution of PNG images.

**Note** that there is an error in the video. The author first uses `latex` and then `pdflatex` three times. That is not a good idea, since they have different capabilities w.r.t. graphics. Stick with `pdflatex`.